# Android: BlackScreen in Application

Tags: android, cordova

In my application when I move from index1.html to index2.html,It shows black screen while retriving large amount of data from the server, stored in local database and retrieving the data from local database in onload of index2.html.How to show the progress bar when the black screen is appeared or how to remove that black screen?.

**update**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Login</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/phonegap-1.0.0.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="master.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">

function submit()
{
alert("welcome");
window.open("index2.html");//while loading index2.html i need the progress bar
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.ex2{
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-color:#FBB917;
    border: 1px solid;
   }
    body {
        font-family:Arial,Geneva,Verdana,sans-serif;
        font-size: 0.8em;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    #loadingScreen {
        background: url(images/ajax-loader.gif) no-repeat 5px 8px;
        padding-left: 25px;
    }
    /* hide the close x on the loading screen */
    .loadingScreenWindow .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
        display: none;
    }
  </style>
   </head>
  <body >

   <input type="button" style="width:80%" value="Submit" onClick="submit()"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Android code

```
public class MobilyzerActivity extends DroidGap {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      //  setContentView(R.layout.main);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

Comment: post your code snippet and we will help you..

Comment: Are you calling the phonegap scripts again in your index2.html page?

Comment: can you show your loadurl() method also.

Comment: i cant understand ?loadurl is to,load the index.html from activity class,i never used anywhere

Comment: @Ela - Saw you are using phonegap-1.0.0 if your starting new project better start with latest: http://phonegap.com/download

Answer (score 0):

If you are using frameworks like JQueryMobile then you have the option of showing loading dialog.
showing

```
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg()
```

hiding

```
$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg()
```

Are you using plain HTML?? any framework??