# issues in phonegap android version(1.7)

Tags: android, cordova

Previously i have used phonegap 1.1.0 jar, 1.1.0 js and plugins like childbrowser and system notification.It was working fine.I have a problem for blackscreen application([Android: BlackScreen in Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492786/android-blackscreen-in-application))

so I have used cordova-1.7.0.jar and cordova-1.7.0.js in android phonegap app.But I am getting error in the plugin.

**Error**
at Compile time

context cannot loaded,many classes cant imported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old plugins are incompatable with the current version, best to reinstall the plugins from scratch.

see:
http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/migrating-your-phonegap-plugins-to.html